# How to handle hash join in SSIS

Tags: join, ssis

I have two tables, each with a HashByte (MD5) Binary(50) field in.  I'm trying to perform a JOIN on SSIS using MERGE JOIN stage, and while I KNOW that there are matches between the tables (I loaded the tables manually), they are not matching in the MERGE JOIN stage.

How do I handle JOINS on fields using Binary(50) HASHBYTE(MD5) values?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: MERGE join requires them to be ordered. Are they ordered? Why do a merge join in a package when you can do it in the database?

Comment: yes.  it is ordered.  It comes in that way.  The end result is a repeat of this join for about 10 tables.  It means I do the above 9 more times.  all in the same manner.  it just runs faster in the package this way.

Comment: I'm interested - you ran the equivalent thing in SQL and you say the package gives you a faster result? Anyway, just keep in mind that unless you have an `order by` in the sql feeding the join, it is not guaranteed to be ordered. Based on the info you mention so far I can't explain why they wouldn't join. You could try putting a sort in the SSIS stream just to confirm whether or not that is the problem.

Comment: I put an image of what I'm doing.  could the binary(50) data type be a problem?  I'll try the sort thing.

Comment: Does `GET AGENT_SKs` have an order by in the SQL statement?

Comment: yes.  all SQL Sources have ORDER BY AGENT_SK

Comment: to answer your question, the package only calls on MLS (initial SQL Query) onces, and then amends it 9 times.  a script will call it 9 more times.

Comment: There's no amending happening in that package. You can write one sql statement that joins together 9 tables in one go.

Comment: no.  because the other queries are aggregate queries. count this, sum that, and it repeats it nine times.  The target table is an aggregate table. Count for 30 days, count for 90 days, sum for 30 days, sum for 90 days.  count something else for 360 days and so forth.

Comment: So either way you are revisiting the table repeatedly. Anyway.. is AGENT_SK is the binary field you are talking about? Is the data type `BINARY(50)` I'll try it now and see if it works for me

Comment: yeah.  AGENT_SK is BINARY(50).  thanks.

Comment: sorts didn't work.  thanks for the idea tho.  I'm interested in what you come up with.

Comment: I'm still trying to get SSDT installed, but.... how do you know they don't match? Do you eventually write all that out to a table? Or do you see no rows going through the final data pipe? Are you using inner or outer joins?

Comment: from the perspective of the top source connector it's all left outer joins. I tried inner join once to see if t's just me, and no.  nothing matches. yes.  when the 9 LOJs are done, it gets inserted into a table.

Comment: I just tested this myself and it joined OK. There must be some difference. I suggest you create a new package and only join one table to another and in your select, only select a single row that you _know for sure_ matches and test it. I also suggest you test it in SQL.